# 100k+ Records and sp_xml_preparedocument

Tags: xml, ssms

I've been encountering a seeming deadlock with one of my tables and the only place I can trace it back to is a stored procedure that uses sp_xml_preparedocument on a list of data. The data inserted, btw, consists of a 100k+ records on average. Is it possible that it is causing the deadlock? What other pitfalls does using sp_xml_preparedocument have?

For future reference, I'd also like to know what other things I should consider before rushing in and using sp_xml_preparedocument

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187367.aspx) notes explain, many things!! For example: **sp_xml_preparedocument limits the number of elements that can be open at one time to 256.**